# Reverse Filter and count multiple numbers over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, medical

I have a data set like this:

```
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7)
Age<- c(10, 21, 51, 42, 35,99,25) 
SurgicalProcedureNumber <- c(21356, 21424, 221356, NA, 12345, 54321,NA) 
OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber   <- c(54321, NA, 21356, 12345, NA,12345, 21424) 
BloodLoss<-c(5,4,5,10,5,15,9)
YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber<-c(11111,22222,NA, 33333,21356,555555,NA)

dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Age, SurgicalProcedureNumber, 
OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber, BloodLoss,YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber)
```

There were certain surgical procedures I cared about that I wanted to filter for:

```
NumbersIcareAbout<- c(21356,21424)
```

I filtered the data over multiple columns to detect any time one of the numbers I cared about popped up. I saved that result as a new dataset of patients with those procedures done. Did so like this:

```
NewData<-dataset %>%
  filter(SurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout | 
       OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout | 
       YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout)
```

But now I want to find out in the new data, what OTHER surgical procedure numbers (which were in multiple columns) showed up and how many of them.  I.e. its not a blank NA, and its not just one of the surgical procedures I originally filtered for.

For instance the result I'm looking for would show that in these select patients who had 21356 and/or 21424 done to them, they also had  ##### and ##### procedures done a certain number of times, which might be spread out over multiple columns.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyr)
NewData %>% 
  gather(key="typeofProcedure",
         value = "procedureNr",
         contains("Procedure")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(procedureNr),
         !procedureNr %in% NumbersIcareAbout) %>% 
  group_by(PatientNum,procedureNr) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

To start, we can use `filter_at` to automatically filter based on multiple columns without having to specify them manually. Then we `gather` the data into a long format with each procedure having a separate row. We then `filter` out `NA` rows, and `arrange` for ease of reading.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- dataset %>%
    filter_at(vars(contains('SurgicalProcedureNumber')), any_vars(. %in% c(21356,21424)))%>%
    gather(key = procedure, value = proc_num,
           contains('SurgicalProcedureNumber')) %>%
    filter(!is.na(proc_num)) %>%
    arrange(PatientNum)
df

   PatientNum Age BloodLoss                         procedure proc_num
1           1  10         5           SurgicalProcedureNumber    21356
2           1  10         5      OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber    54321
3           1  10         5 YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber    11111
4           2  21         4           SurgicalProcedureNumber    21424
5           2  21         4 YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber    22222
6           3  51         5           SurgicalProcedureNumber   221356
7           3  51         5      OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber    21356
8           5  35         5           SurgicalProcedureNumber    12345
9           5  35         5 YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber    21356
10          7  25         9      OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber    21424
```

In this long format, it is really easy to see which procedures with which numbers were done on each patient since they're all in a single column instead of spread across many.